# MongoDB auto-increment field and read order

Tags: mongodb, auto-increment

I have a multi-instance service that writes about ~100 documents per second to a Mongo database.

Now I'm working on an application that must process those documents in the order they were inserted.

I'm stuck with this requirement of strict sequential processing order.

I'd like to avoid any queue messaging systems for this, so the easiest solution could be to add a unique auto-increment field to every document and then call the `find()` method to get some documents that have the field value greater than the last processed document has.
I've read [this official article](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-optimistic-loop) about creating an auto-increment fields in Mongo, but does this approach guarantee the write order?

Let's say, there is this sequence of operations that happens in the order specified, but with no delay in between (with inital value of the auto-increment field = 0):

1. Instance #1 of the service calls `db.collection.insertOne()` with a huge complex document #1, that may make Mongo to take some time to process it.
2. Instance #2 calls `insertOne()` with a small simple document #2.
3. My app executes `find()` on the same collection.

Is there any chance that the `find()` method in the step 3 will return only document #2 with the value of the auto-increment field = 2, and few moments later document #1 will be finally written to the database with the value = 1?

Basically, I'm afraid that the auto-increment field's value could be bumped before the corresponding document will be available for reads, so the next document could be visible to client before the first one, despite having higher field's value.

#### Update:

Here is a timeline of what I think could happen:

[image: timeline]

Comment: Documents #1 and #2 will both have the same _id, which is calculated prior to either of these documents existing. Whichever document ends up being inserted second will fail the index uniqueness constraint and won't be inserted. So you wouldn't be able to have them both exist in the database.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood me. I'm not using the standard _id generation algorithm, I want to use the auto-increment implementation from [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-optimistic-loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the situation described in my question, when the later inserted document #2 becomes visible before document #1, is not possible, at least with a standalone Mongo instance.

MongoDB guarantees monotonic writes in this case:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#monotonic-writes

Answer (score 0):

Your document #2 can only have _id=2 if document #1 with _id=1 has already been written to the database.

Therefore the situation as you described it cannot happen - you cannot be constructing your document #2 with _id=2 on the client side if there isn't a document #1 already in the database. Persistence operations for documents #1 and #2, if they have different _id values, must be sequential (non-overlapping).

Comment: Well, the question is - will document #1 be written to the database before the document #2? Getting a new _id and persisting a document are basically two operations, right? So, is there a guarantee in Mongo that the insertOne() operation for the document #1 will persist it to the database before the document #2, even if the document #1 is larger and requires more time to process than the document #2?

Comment: You are confused about the sequence of operations. Write them out on a piece of paper and separate id retrieval from database, document construction on client side, initiation of write operation for each of the documents.